# delete the words with length greater than X in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub, corpus

In R programming after i remove the punctuation, numbers and non-ascii characters, i remained with many words with long characters:

```
ques1<-gsub("[[:digit:]]"," ", ques1,perl=TRUE)
ques1<-gsub("[[:punct:]]"," ", ques1,perl=TRUE)

ques1<-iconv(ques1, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=" ")
ques1<-rm_white(ques1)
ques1
```

I checked the longest length of character is 35 using

```
max(nchar(strsplit(ques1, " ")[[1]]))
[1] 35
```

Now, i want to remove the words which has more than 10 characters, as i didn't want them, such as

```
wwwhotmailcomlearnbyexample
```

Please help me out !!!

Comment: Why don't you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Prolly `ques1[ nchar(ques1) <= 10 ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following gsub:

```
ques1 = "A long sentence with long wwwhotmailcomlearnbyexample"
gsub("\\b[[:alpha:]]{11,}\\b", "", ques1, perl=T)
```

The `\\b[[:alpha:]]{11,}\\b` regex will match words with length of 11 or more (`\\b` is a word boundary and `[:alpha:]` stands for any letter).

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4UcZPu)